# jQuery passing click selector into IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, dialog, facebox

I am trying to create a jQuery function to check whether a Cancel or Remove button was pressed on a facebox dialog, however I am not quite sure how to go about it.

Right now, I have:

```
// Confirm and remove group members
$("[id^='removeGroupMember_']").click(function () {
        confirmDialog('Removal', 'Are you sure you want to remove this person from the group?');

        //  I need to check the results of the confirm dialog prior
        //  to calling the code below to remove the actual rows

        $(this).parent().slideUp("fast", function () {
            $(this).remove();
            updateGroupRows();
        });
    return false;
});
```

Where `confirmDialog` is:

```
function confirmDialog(action, message) {
    $.facebox('<h3 class="confirmHeader light tb">Confirm ' + action + '</h3><div class="confirmContent"><p>' + message + '</p><a href="#" id="dialogConfirmAction" class="ras small red button right">' + action + '</a><a href="#" id="dialogConfirmCancel" class="ras small gray button right">Cancel</a></div>');
};
```

Right now, I have two functions for when those buttons are pressed, but I'm not sure how to check their result and feed that back in so I can decide whether or not to delete the associated row:

```
$('#dialogConfirmAction').live('click', function() {
    console.log('Yep... they dun clicked it.');
    return true;
});

$('#dialogConfirmCancel').live('click', function() {
    $.facebox.close();
    return true;
});
```

Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is change your `confirmDialog` function to be like so:

```
function confirmDialog(action, message, actionfunc) {
    $.facebox('<h3 class="confirmHeader light tb">Confirm ' + action + '</h3><div class="confirmContent"><p>' + message + '</p><a href="#" id="dialogConfirmAction" class="ras small red button right">' + action + '</a><a href="#" id="dialogConfirmCancel" class="ras small gray button right">Cancel</a></div>');
    if(actionfunc) {
        $('#dialogConfirmAction').click(actionfunc);
    }
};
```

You can then pass what you want to happen "on action" by passing a function to the `confirmDialog` function. This would make your other code look like this:

```
$("[id^='removeGroupMember_']").click(function () {
    var $that = $(this);
    confirmDialog('Removal', 'Are you sure you want to remove this person from the group?',
                  function() {
                      //This function will be run when the "action" link is clicked
                      $that.parent().slideUp("fast", function () {
                          $(this).remove();
                          updateGroupRows();
                      });
                  });
    return false;
});
```

And you can extend that by adding another variable to say what to do on cancel.

Comment: I made a typo when I first posted this, the selector in confirmDialog function was for the cancel button. I've fixed it.

Comment: I owe you one very giant beer my friend.  Essentially, you created a callback function, right?  By the way, I ended up caching the selector since calling `$(this).parent()` would mean calling the modal box instead of the original list item.

Comment: @iWasRobbed: Yep, that's basically what I did. And, yeah sorry. Haha I just copied the workings from your original click function into the new one. I'll edit it for the sake of completeness. **Edit** Fixed!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 // Confirm and remove group members
$("[id^='removeGroupMember_']").click(function () {

        if(confirmDialog('Removal', 'Are you sure you want to remove this person from the group?')) {
            //  I need to check the results of the confirm dialog prior
            //  to calling the code below to remove the actual rows

            $(this).parent().slideUp("fast", function () {
                $(this).remove();
                updateGroupRows();
            });
        }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user341652: Just so you know, this doesn't work because `confirmDialog` is a) not the same as the `confirm()` function and b) the function creates a pop up which is not modal so there's no way it could properly return true or false to the calling function.